# How to take an element from a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to retrieve the first 5 stock elements from [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers) 
([TTD, WST, TDG, ODFL, VMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlGWl.png)) and put them in a list using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers')

change = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Change"]')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
#stockname = driver.find_element_by_id('')

for i in range(2):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3600).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scr-  res-table"]/div[1]/table/thead/tr/th[4]'))).click()


link = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Fw(600)')
print(link.text)
```

Comment: Not clear to me.Are looking for to select those `TTD, WST, TDG, ODFL, VMI` check box and then get value from table cell and store in a list?

Comment: yes exactly, I wanna chose those as a string and store them in a list

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want stored in the list? The text of the ticker or the actual element? If it's the latter, what part of the element, the row, the a tag...?

Comment: The text of the ticker yes, as in "TTD" or "WST" so the list would like this liste = ["TTD","WST","TDG","ODFL","VMI"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a real tricky one If you click on `change` link not sure how many times to click to get the element you are after since this information not always comes in first click.

Try Below code hope this helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers')
#Cookie pop up to handle if not there then ignore
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='I agree']"))).click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250)")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="scr-res-table"]/div[1]/table/thead/tr/th[4]/span[text()="Change"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
while(True):
    try:
        print("running...")
        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='TTD']")))
        tablerows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='fin-scr-res-table']//table[1]/tbody//tr")))
        for row in tablerows:
            if row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text in ['TTD', 'WST', 'TDG', 'ODFL', 'VMI']:
                coldata = [td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td") if td.text != '']
                print(coldata)
        break

    except:
          print("exception block")
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
          continue
```

This will print on console like this.You can remove unused print option.

```
running...
exception block
running...
exception block
running...
['WST', 'West Pharmaceutical Services, Inc.', '187.61', '+17.49', '+10.28%', '431,280', '509,179', '13.854B', '58.45']
['TTD', 'The Trade Desk, Inc.', '260.30', '+16.11', '+6.60%', '2.135M', '2.115M', '11.971B', '114.55']
['TDG', 'TransDigm Group Incorporated', '318.01', '+13.75', '+4.52%', '262,441', '847,228', '17.073B', '24.77']
['ODFL', 'Old Dominion Freight Line, Inc.', '138.97', '+10.72', '+8.36%', '765,680', '939,080', '16.607B', '27.21']
['VMI', 'Valmont Industries, Inc.', '115.11', '+9.64', '+9.14%', '143,588', '138,449', '2.478B', '16.30']
```

---

**UPDATE**

To get only first five records from table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers')
#Cookie pop up to handle if not there then ignore
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='I agree']"))).click()
tablerows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='fin-scr-res-table']//table[1]/tbody//tr")))
for row in tablerows[:5]:
    coldata = [td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td") if td.text != '']
    print(coldata)
```

**Output**:

```
['RLLCF', 'Rolls-Royce Holdings plc', '0.0125', '+0.0050', '+66.67%', '38.796M', '3.637M', '272.509B', 'N/A']
['IMMU', 'Immunomedics, Inc.', '27.00', '+5.01', '+22.78%', '20.966M', '3.661M', '5.776B', 'N/A']
['PBI-PB', 'Pitney Bowes Inc. NT 43', '15.20', '+2.33', '+18.12%', '116,008', 'N/A', '2.833B', '11.53']
['KZMYY', 'KAZ Minerals PLC', '2.7500', '+0.3552', '+14.83%', '34,267', '44,605', '2.555B', '4.70']
['FWONK', 'Formula One Group', '29.39', '+3.59', '+13.91%', '3.22M', '2.083M', '6.742B', 'N/A']
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the idea was that the list updates every day with the new top 5 stocks. So one day the list would be ['TTD', 'WST', 'TDG', 'ODFL', 'VMI'] and then I would run the script the next day and the list would be the top 5 stocks

Comment: Ok got it.Then its a very easy one.You should have mentioned that only first five records.

Comment: @Vista : check the updated answer is that you are after?

Comment: Dude your a lifesaver

Comment: Yep that's the one

Comment: ile "/Users/roman/Desktop/NSI/trading bot/topstocks.py", line 11, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Vista: Copy and paste my entire code and it should work.The reason you getting timeout i guess you haven't click on accept cookie button.

Comment: Ok, I just made my account here and I already adore this community. Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: I am glad to help.

Comment: One more question tho, sometimes the code returns this error selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @Vista :I would request please post a new question and mentioned where you are getting error.